# how to break table values in two portion on one page in html

Tags: html, css, html-table

how to break table values in two portion on one page in html
need to load this table value after breaking from s.no 6  into two portions example image is uploaded  what happing is after page over it goes to second page in print view side to side
kindly help stuck from two days

```
   ---------------------------
  |s.no | product | Qty |Price|
  -----------------------------
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
       <head>

        </head>
       <body>

       <h2>HTML Table</h2>

  <table>
    <tr>
     <th>s.no</th>
     <th>product</th>
     <th>qty</th>
     <th>price</th>
    </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>1</td>
       <td>Maria Anders</td>
       <td>1</td>
       <td>110</td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>2</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
       <td>2</td>
       <td>110</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
 <td>3</td>
 <td>Maria Anders</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>110</td>
                </tr>
                         <tr>
                            <td>4</td>
                    <td>Maria Anders</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>110</td>
                        </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td>5</td>
                              <td>Maria Anders</td>
                              <td>1</td>
                               <td>110</td>
                                 </tr>
                                   <tr>
                                     <td>6</td>
                                     <td>Maria Anders</td>
                                     <td>1</td>
                                     <td>110</td>
                                     </tr>
                                     <tr>
                                    <td>7</td>
                                    <td>Maria Anders</td>
                                    <td>1</td>
                                      <td>110</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                    <td>8</td>
                                      <td>Maria Anders</td>
                                      <td>1</td>
                                      <td>110</td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                      <td>9</td>
                                     <td>Maria Anders</td>
                                     <td>1</td>
                                     <td>110</td>
                                       </tr>
                                     <tr>
                                     <td>10</td>
                                     <td>Maria Anders</td>
                                     <td>1</td>
                                      <td>110</td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                      <td>11</td>
                                      <td>Maria Anders</td>
                                     <td>1</td>
                                     <td>110</td>
                                     </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                      <td>12</td>
                                     <td>Maria Anders</td>
                                     <td>1</td>
                                    <td>110</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                <td>13</td>
                                  <td>Maria Anders</td>
                                    <td>1</td>
                                  <td>110</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                <td>14</td>
                              <td>Maria Anders</td>
                              <td>1</td>
                             <td>110</td>
                              </tr>
                               </table>

                                   </body>
                    </html>
```

need to load this table value after breaking from s.no 6  into two portions example image is uploaded  what happing is after page over it goes to second page in print view side to side
kindly help stuck from two days

[image: example image which i want to code]

Comment: Please put a little more effort in your question by removing template message (enter image description here).  Also post data here instead of an external image.  Show whatever code you have so far.

Comment: detail added kindly view

Comment: Why don't you just create two tables?

Answer (score 1):

Use two tables, float the first one left:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
       <head>
<style>
  table, th, td { border: 1px solid black; }
  table {  border-collapse: collapse; }
</style>
        </head>
       <body>

       <h2>HTML Table</h2>

  <table style="float: left">
    <tr>
     <th>s.no</th>
     <th>product</th>
     <th>qty</th>
     <th>price</th>
    </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>1</td>
       <td>Maria Anders</td>
       <td>1</td>
       <td>110</td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>2</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
       <td>2</td>
       <td>110</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
 <td>3</td>
 <td>Maria Anders</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>110</td>
                </tr>
                         <tr>
                            <td>4</td>
                    <td>Maria Anders</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>110</td>
                        </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td>5</td>
                              <td>Maria Anders</td>
                              <td>1</td>
                               <td>110</td>
                                 </tr>
                                   <tr>
                                     <td>6</td>
                                     <td>Maria Anders</td>
                                     <td>1</td>
                                     <td>110</td>
                                     </tr>
</table>
<table>
                                     <tr>
                                    <td>7</td>
                                    <td>Maria Anders</td>
                                    <td>1</td>
                                      <td>110</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                    <td>8</td>
                                      <td>Maria Anders</td>
                                      <td>1</td>
                                      <td>110</td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                      <td>9</td>
                                     <td>Maria Anders</td>
                                     <td>1</td>
                                     <td>110</td>
                                       </tr>
                                     <tr>
                                     <td>10</td>
                                     <td>Maria Anders</td>
                                     <td>1</td>
                                      <td>110</td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                      <td>11</td>
                                      <td>Maria Anders</td>
                                     <td>1</td>
                                     <td>110</td>
                                     </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                      <td>12</td>
                                     <td>Maria Anders</td>
                                     <td>1</td>
                                    <td>110</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                <td>13</td>
                                  <td>Maria Anders</td>
                                    <td>1</td>
                                  <td>110</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                <td>14</td>
                              <td>Maria Anders</td>
                              <td>1</td>
                             <td>110</td>
                              </tr>
                               </table>

                                   </body>
                    </html>
```

Comment: my table data dynamically in one table just want break the table data in to two portion side to side because i donot want second page

Comment: Either do this like above (possible via javascript) or use a flexbox if you want dynamic behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an item use 2 columns with `<td colspan="2">`.
For more info:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp